# Hide blocks from the administration page according to the user role

Tags: 7, blocks

Is there a way that certain roles can only manipulate blocks that are assigned to them?

That is, if a user with an a editor role enters to `"admin/structure/block"`, I just want you to see and be able to manipulate the blocks that I define, the rest of the blocks must remain hidden for this user / role.

Is this possible to do?.

Comment: Sounds like a custom module which checks the permission for the user and that block....

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you will need a custom page, the "admin / structure / block" won't do the work.